# RewriteRule htaccess not show images

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with showing images on my site when using RewriteRule on .htaccess file.

In a nutshell, I have many pages with GET variables that I want to transform.
For example:

http://example.com/home.php?page=categorie  =>  http://example.com/categorie

http://example.com/home.php?page=categorie&act=view&lettera=A  =>  http://example.com/categorie/A

I can do this , using this .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^categorie$ /home.php?page=categorie [L]
RewriteRule ^categorie/([^/]*)$ /home.php?page=categorie&act=view&lettera=$1 [L]
```

When I go on http://example.com/categorie not have any problem.

When I go on http://example.com/categorie/A can't see any style,js,images.

So, I add this line:

```
RewriteRule ^categorie/(css|img|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|js|svg)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

And when I go on http://example.com/categorie/A can see the css style only.
Any Idea?

Comment: The well-known solution to this is to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to the relevant `RewriteRule`.

Comment: If you enable RewriteLog and watch the file you can see what your server is doing for each requested URL. It really helps when debugging rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Answer (score 0):

when you go to `/home.php?page=categorie&act=view&lettera={val}` page directly can you see the images? unless the image path are being referenced as `categorie/A` it should be left intact. you don't need the last rule where you define file/image extensions.

go to the page with issues `categorie/A` and fire up `firebug` in firefox. Go over the image that's missing and do a inspect element to debug why the images aren't showing, maybe urls got rewritten somehow.

Comment: Yes, when I go to '/home.php?page=categorie&act=view&lettera={val}' I can see the images, the path is 'image/logo.svg'
When I go to 'categorie/A' the path is the same: 'image/logo.svg' , so if I replace with '../image/logo.svg' I can see. But how to do this automatically for all paths?

Comment: so the images are being references as image/logo.svg and you're able to paste the asset url in the browser and can access the image?

Comment: If I go to example.com/image/logo.svg I can see the image

Comment: you can just do /image if image folder is in your root web server document path.

Comment: Solves just adding this: <base href="/" />

Answer (score 0):

By rewriting the URL to a different depth, relative URLs also need to change. So, for instance, if `<img src="../images/myimage.jpg">` worked on `/home.php?...`, the src would need to change to `<img src="../../images/myimage.jpg">` for `/category/A`.

Easiest option is to make sure your image URLs use paths that are relative to the root, not to the document, i.e. `<img src="/images/myimage.jpg">`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ user.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^country/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ country.php?countryname=$1 [L]
url1: http://domain.com/Rocky
url2: http://domain.com/country/India 
Add <base href="../"> in country.php<head>
<head>
<base href="../">
</head>
```

Comment: Could you introduce the code snippet with an explanation ?